# $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\{x \in E : |f_n(x)|>N\}}|f_n(x)|dx = 0.$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\sup_n \| f_n \|_p < \infty\  \mbox{ for some } p > 1,$$

where

$$\|g\|_p := \Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g(x)|^p dx \Big)^{1/p}.$$

Show that

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{n \geq1} \int_{\{x \in E : |f_n(x)|>N\}}|f_n(x)|dx = 0.$$

**Attempt.** I am able  to show that for all $n$,

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\{x \in E : |f_n(x)|>N\}}|f_n(x)|dx = 0.$$

But what I need is uniform convergence and I am not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: Looks like a "uniform integrability" type problem. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to apply it here. I decode too little information from the assumption, that's why I didn't get uniform convergence.

Comment: Does $E$ have finite measure?  It can be proven from first principles and Jensen's inequality if so...else I need to think about it more.

Comment: Nope $E$ need not have finite measure.

Comment: $$\int_{\{|f_n|> N\}} |f_n| dx = \int_{\{|f_n|> N\}} \frac{|f_n|^p}{|f_n|^{p-1}} dx \leq N^{1-p} \int_{\{|f_n|> N\}} |f_n|^p dx \leq N^{1-p} \|f_n\|_p^p \leq (\sup_n \|f_n\|_p)^p N^{1-p}.$$

Comment: Thank you nguyen. Your answer is enlightening.